# trying to run a c++ file that gets a function from another file gives an error

Tags: c++

I am using vs codium
my files are main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int add(int x, int y); // needed so main.cpp knows that add() is a function defined elsewhere

int main()
{
    std::cout << "The sum of 3 and 4 is: " << add(3, 4) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

and add.cpp:

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

I compiled the program using clang
it gives me:

```
Executing task: & "C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang++" -std=c++20 -fdiagnostics-color=always -g main.cpp add.cpp -o D:\something\something\C++\main.exe

LINK : D:\something\something\C++\main.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

this creates a main.exe

my tasks.json file is:({

```
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",

"tasks": [
{
"type": "shell",
"label": "C/C++: clang++.exe build active file",
"command": "C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang++",
"args": [
"-std=c++20",
"-fdiagnostics-color=always",
"-g",
"main.cpp",
"add.cpp",
"-o",
"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
],
"options": {
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
},
"group": {
"kind": "build",
"isDefault": true
},
"detail": "Task generated by Debugger.",
"problemMatcher": []
}
]
}
)
```

and it creates a main.exe file but when I run main in vs codium(using the main.exe file in the directory does nothing) it just give me this:
`C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\10\AppData\Local\Temp\ccNUNMZA.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to add(int, int collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

error and deleted the main.exe file
I know i can use "#" instead but it will run the program inside the main.cpp file and I don't want that

Comment: You likely have not saved the file add.cpp

Comment: The steps you describe would not produce the error you describe.  There is a mistake happening somewhere that isn't described in this question.

Comment: Try to switch the places of `add.cpp` and `main.cpp` (so that `add.cpp` comes before `main.cpp`).

Comment: Can you format your JSON file?

Comment: wdym format? you mean how my task.json actually looks?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're encountering an "undefined reference" error when trying to compile and run your C++ program in VS Codium. This error typically occurs when the linker is unable to find the definition of a function that is being used in your code.

In your case, the error message suggests that the linker cannot find the definition of the add function. This could happen if the add.cpp file is not being properly compiled and linked with the main.cpp file.

To fix this issue, you can try the following steps:

Make sure that both main.cpp and add.cpp are located in the same directory.

Update your tasks.json file to include the necessary flags and options for linking the add.cpp file. Replace the existing tasks.json content with the following code:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "C/C++: clang++.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang++",
        "args": [
            "-std=c++20",
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "main.cpp",
            "add.cpp",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger.",
        "problemMatcher": [],
        "dependsOn": "clean"
    },
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "C/C++: clean",
        "command": "rm",
        "args": [
            "-rf",
            "${fileDirname}/*.exe"
        ],
        "windows": {
            "command": "del",
            "args": [
                "/Q",
                "${fileDirname}\\*.exe"
            ]
        },
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
]
```

This updated tasks.json file includes an additional task called "clean" that deletes the existing .exe files before compiling. This ensures that the linker performs a full link when compiling the program.

After updating the tasks.json file, try compiling and running your program again using VS Codium. The "clean" task will delete any existing .exe files before compiling, which may help resolve the "undefined reference" error.
If you still encounter the error, double-check that the file names and paths are correct, and that the necessary compiler and linker flags are being used. Additionally, ensure that you have the necessary permissions to create files in the specified directory.

I hope this helps!

Comment: problem persist, file names are correct(wdym by paths are correct?), they are in the same folder and wdym "that the necessary compiler and linker flags are being used"? sorry i am new to programing

Comment: tbh i dont remember, i had a weird thing last night. Im not smart with coding... im only just now becoming good at JS. however when i have those weird moments, what i say is true or has good meaning. so i suppose this somehow makes sense. im the so smart im dumb kinda person